# Android app will only display one JSON element

Tags: android, json, okhttp

[image: Here is a picture of the screen output]I'm making an app for class that is to retrieve stock information from an API. I have set up a way to retrieve JSON data based on a user's input stock symbol. There are two textviews right now, one that shows the company name and one that shows the stock change value. However, only the textview that has its text set first is displayed, then the other one is unaffected.
Here is the console output when the search button is clicked:

04-24 23:24:29.782 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6357)
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:909)
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4690)
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:11801)
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11765)
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11749)
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6850)
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4057)
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3915)
04-24 23:24:29.783 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3890)
04-24 23:24:29.784 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at com.webdesigners.stockmarket.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:74)
04-24 23:24:29.784 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
04-24 23:24:29.784 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
04-24 23:24:29.784 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-24 23:24:29.784 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-24 23:24:29.784 8144-8589/com.webdesigners.stockmarket W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

```
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userSymbol = searchEditText.getText().toString();

            try
            {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22" + userSymbol + "%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json").build();
                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful())
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String responseData = response.body().string();
                            try
                            {
                                TextView symbol = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.symbol);
                                TextView change = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.change);

                                //get object at "quote" level where most attributes are
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseData);
                                JSONObject query = jsonObject.getJSONObject("query");
                                JSONObject results = query.getJSONObject("results");
                                JSONObject quote = results.getJSONObject("quote");

                                Long changeValue = quote.getLong("Change");
                                String changeString = Long.toString(changeValue);
                                assert change != null;
                                change.setText(changeString);

                                assert symbol != null;
                                String companyName = quote.getString("Name");
                                String companyNameConcat = "Name: " + companyName;
                                symbol.setText(companyNameConcat);

                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callbacks are executed not on the main thread. That is the reason for the errors you see.
Call runOnUiThread when you need to update the UI.

Comment: This worked! I just put the text setters inside of a runOnUiThread(new Runnable(...)) method and it worked! Thanks

Comment: That's awesome @Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

After the

```
String responseData = response.body().string();
try
{
```

put a for loop there. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
// Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Long changeValue = quote.getLong("Change");
String changeString = Long.toString(changeValue);
assert change != null;
change.setText(changeString);
```

//Change the above code to

```
assert change != null;
String changeValue = quote.getString("Change");
change.setText(changeValue);
```

Store `change` as `String`, retrieve it as `String` and convert to `Long`